# Angular Material md-datepicker and md-select validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have a form with input fields, datepickers, and dropdowns. On submit, if the required input fields are not filled out, they are underscored with a red line. I would like the datepickers and dropdowns to also be underscored if not selected - at the moment they do nothing.

Code:

```
  <div class="input-section-title">Information</div>

  <div layout="row"
       layout-align="start start">

    <md-datepicker id="date"
                   ng-model="vm.submissionDate"
                   md-placeholder="Date*"
                   required></md-datepicker>

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container padded-input md-block"
                        flex-gt-sm="">
      <label>Type*</label>
      <md-select id="information-type"
                 ng-model="vm.type"
                 required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="type in vm.dropdowns.types"
                   value="{{type}}">
          {{type}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container"
                        flex="15">
      <label>NVRA*</label>
      <md-select id="information-nlba"
                 ng-model="vm.code"
                 required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="code in vm.dropdowns.codes"
                   value="{{code}}">
          {{code}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

  </div>

  <div class="input-section-title">Personal Information</div>

  <div layout="row" layout-align="start start">

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container" flex>
      <label>Last Name*</label>
      <input id="personal-information-last-name"
             ng-model="vm.vitals.last" required>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container padded-input" flex>
      <label>First Name*</label>
      <input id="personal-information-first-name"
             ng-model="vm.vitals.first" required>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container padded-input" flex>
      <label>Middle Name</label>
      <input id="personal-information-middle-name"
             ng-model="vm.vitals.middle">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="form-input-container" flex="15">
      <label>Suffix</label>
      <md-select id="personal-information-suffix"
                 ng-model="vm.vitals.suffix">
        <md-option ng-repeat="suffix in vm.dropdowns.suffixes"
                   value="{{suffix}}">
          {{suffix}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker) supports ng-messages you can use the following code.

```
<md-datepicker id="date"
               name='date'
               ng-model="vm.submissionDate"
               md-placeholder="Date*"
               required>
</md-datepicker>
<div class="errors" ng-messages="newForm.date.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
</div>
```

and same goes for [select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select)

```
<md-input-container class="form-input-container padded-input md-block"
                    flex-gt-sm="">
  <label>Type*</label>
  <md-select id="information-type"
             name="type"
             ng-model="vm.type"
             required>
    <md-option ng-repeat="type in vm.dropdowns.types"
               value="{{type}}">
      {{type}}
    </md-option>
  </md-select>
   <div class="errors" ng-messages="newForm.type.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
</div>
</md-input-container>
```

For Validation to work you must wrap you div within `form` tag and assign name using `name` attribute and use that name for validation of different elements.

check the following pen UI is not good but you will get the basic idea.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/xVOMQB

Comment: Thanks, I did wrap in a form, just didn't copy/paste that part. I'll try this and report back. Ideally I'd add just the red underline rather than actual text, but this could work.